# Issues with SQL Select utilizing Except and UNION All

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select *
From (
Select a
    Except
Select b
) x

UNION ALL

Select *
From (
Select b
    Except
Select a
) y
```

This sql statement returns an extremely wrong amount of data.  If Select a returns a million, how does this entire statement return 100,000?  In this instance, Select b contains mutually exclusive data, so there should be no elimination due to the except.

Comment: `EXCEPT` does an implicit `DISTINCT`, according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx, and the `ALL` in your `UNION ALL` cannot re-create the duplicates.

Comment: Is there a non distinct EXCEPT alternative?

Comment: You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: BTW: Is your main request to get all data that is only contained in one but not both tables?

Comment: The main goal is to get any data that is in one table but not the other, regardless of which table it is.  My sample data, at the moment, contains mutually exclusive data.  So I knew the count was off.

Comment: Is this in mysql or Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, EXCEPT does an implicit DISTINCT, according to <kbd>[this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)</kbd> and the ALL in your UNION ALL cannot re-create the duplicates. Hence you cannot use your approach if you want to keep duplicates.

As you want to get the data that is contained in exactly one of the tables `a` and `b`, but not in both, a more efficient way to achieve that would be the following (I am just assuming the tables have columns `id` and `c` where `id` is the primary key, as you did not state any column names):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN 'from b' ELSE 'from a' END as source_table
      ,coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id
      ,coalesce(a.c, b.c) as c
  FROM a
       FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND a.c = b.c -- use all columns of both tables here!
 WHERE a.id IS NULL OR b.id IS NULL
```

This makes use of a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, excluding the matching records via the WHERE conditions, as the primary key cannot be null except if it comes from the `OUTER` side.
If your tables do not have primary keys - which is bad practice anyway - you would have to check across all columns for `NULL`, not just the one primary key column.

And if you have records completely consisting of `NULL`s, this method would not work.
Then you could use an approach similar to your original one, just using

```
SELECT ...
 FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE <join by all columns>)

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
 FROM b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE <join by all columns>)
```

Comment: Hmm, the my script is being used to check a data move from an older database to a newer one, with a completely different schema.  The script contains many child tables and is linked through a web of relationships. If a parent table is missing data, then the comparison will show a null for the related relationship column.  This is what created the issue with duplicate records, as the tables should never have dupes due to PKs.  As I do not know which columns may be Null, I am not sure if the above solution will work.

Comment: @Dassina So this would leave you with the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get any data that is in one table and not in the other regardless of which table, I would try something like the following:

```
select id, 'table a data not in b' from a where id not in (select id from b)
union
select id, 'table b data not in a' from b where id not in (select id from a)
```

Comment: The schemas between the tables are different and I cannot reliably assume that I can find the new PK for the associated data, as Parent tables may not have been populated correctly. In most cases this would be a working solution, but not in this case.  So I cannot use this solution.

Comment: Even though the schemas are different you can always just select a subset of the data from both tables, like just the primary key and some other identifier